# Android, how does "Always Open With" save a user's preference

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

When application X fires an implicit Search intent  and user decides to "Always Open with App Y", I am wondering what is being saved?

- Are all Search Intents open with app Y?
- Are only Search Intents coming from app X opened with app Y?
- Are only Search Intents generated from that specific part of application X open in app Y?

Comment: Android stores some info in the system.